# Updating values in cells

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I am struggling to figure out how to update the number value in a given cell with the value an end-user will enter using Application.InputBox. I'm aware there are glaring errors with the code, but because I am new to excel VBA, my debugging skills are not quite there yet and I cannot figure out how to fix them. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub UpdateLinen()

Dim NewLinen As Integer
Dim InputBoxResult As Integer
Dim ExistingValue As Integer
Dim NewValue As Integer

    NewLinen = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many new Linen Bandages are being added?", Type:=1)
    NewLinen = InputBoxResult

    ExistingValue = Range("B4").Value
    NewValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ExistingValue + InputBoxResult)
    Range("B4").Value = NewValue

End Sub
```

Range("B4") already has a number value in the cell, and the idea here is that the end-user will click a button (to which I will assign the macro to when finished) and enter a number value which will be added to that in Range("B4") to give a new number value for that cell. Additionally, I want to write the code such that the end-user can return and update the number value in that cell as many times as they wanted just by clicking the button macro and entering a value.

Comment: `NewLinen = InputBoxResult` makes no sense -- it simply overwrites the number that you just obtained with 0. The line above *does* assign the value of the inputbox to `NewLinen`. You don't have to do something afterwards. Also -- what is the point of `Application.InputBox` rather than simply `InputBox`?

Comment: ^ Well, you have to use the variable ```NewLinen```, and not the empty ```InputBoxResult```

Comment: @JohnColeman [The (Excel Only) `Application.InputBox` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) and [the (generic) `InputBox` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) are actually significantly different: for example, only `Application.InputBox` has the `Type` parameter which lets you specify "numbers only" , "cell reference" or "Array of values "

Comment: @Chronocidal I realize that (I use it when I want users to select range) but OP just wants them to type a number.

Comment: @JohnColeman Which is why OP has used `Type:=1`, so that the user cannot enter `e`, `π`, or `ASDAFS`.  It *also* sets the Return Type to `Double` instead of `String`

Comment: That last bit is not true @Chronocidal =), if `Newlinen` is declared `Long`, input like `5.6` will result in `6` with return type `Long` (`Application.InputBox` does it's own rounding). Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @JvdV Which is an implicit conversion of the `Double` returned by `Application.InputBox` when assigned to a `Long` variable.  Try using `TypeName` directly on the output of `Application.InputBox`, or just `Debug.Print Application.InputBox("Try 5.6",Type:=1)` to see that it doesn't do rounding itself ☺ `InputBox` always outputs a `String`, `Application.InputBox` varies by `Type`

Comment: Touché! @Chronocidal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few comments here:

- Rather use `Long` data type values instead of `Integer` (good habit to prevent overflow issues)
- You don't need `WorksheetFunction.Sum` here to add these values
- You are overwriting your user's input straight away with `NewLinen = InputBoxResult`
- I know you said there will be a button but I like to have the habit of at least an explicit worksheet reference.
- Furthermore, nothing wrong with writing out logic in multiple lines, but really nothing fancy and difficult about this operation, so why not in a single line?

Can I recommend something like:

```
Sub UpdateLinen()

Dim NewLinen As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1")

NewLinen = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many new Linen Bandages are being added?", Type:=1)
ws.Range("B4") = ws.Range("B4") + NewLinen

End Sub
```

Comment: @Sidge, did this help you out?